# Can't get defaultsTo to work with waterline/sailsjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to set a default value to a field when I create a new item in the database, but I can't make it to work.

I am using SailsJS 0.12.1 currently, which is the latest version

This is how my file looks like:

models/Users.js

```
module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {
        firstName: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },
        role: {
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['admin', 'user', 'limited', 'suspended', 'deleted'],
            defaultsTo: 'limited'
        },
    }
}
```

When the element is created in the database, I don't get the `role` value. It looks like that:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56f8616163a59cf813998f8a"
    },
    "firstName": "Alex",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2016-03-27T22:40:33.151Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2016-03-27T22:40:33.151Z"
    }
}
```

Any idea what I forgot?

Thanks!

Comment: try creating with blueprint to test....
localhst:PORT/users/create?firstName=XYZ
and see what are you getting!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue earlier today. I was able to resolve this by adding required is 'true'.

Example of New User Model:

```
 module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {
        firstName: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },
        role: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            enum: ['admin', 'user', 'limited', 'suspended', 'deleted'],
            defaultsTo: 'limited'
        },
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome!! It fixes my issue! Although this doesn't seem to work for nested object, do you have a suggestion?

` attributes: {
   preferences: {
      language: {
          type: 'string',
          defaultsTo: 'en',
          required: true,
      }
   }
 } `

Comment: @alexmngn I am fairly new to SailsJS, but I think the proper way to do something like this would be to have a separate model for preferences. The you would create an association between the two. [SailsJS Associations](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations)